# emacs: assign single key-binding to multiple commands, using the universal argument

Tags: emacs, elisp

Here is my attempt:

```
(global-set-key [M-left] (key-binding (kbd "C-u C-@")))
```

After I evaluate the above expression, invoking `alt` + `left` gives me the message `<M-left> is undefined`. The following, however, works:

```
(global-set-key [M-left] (key-binding (kbd "C-u")))
```

But this is only the `universal argument` part of my command. How do I combine these two commands into one Emacs key-binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this: define a [Keyboard Macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html) interactively or write a function:

```
(define-key global-map [M-left]
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (set-mark-command t)))
```

Answer (score 1):

sds has provided the solutions, but for clarification, if you evaluate `(key-binding (kbd "C-u C-@"))` you'll see that it returns `nil` -- because that is not a bound key sequence.

In fact <kbd>C-u</kbd> runs the command `universal-argument`, which takes care of reading a *subsequent* key sequence from the user (<kbd>C-@</kbd> in your case).